# Twitter Bootstrap for Rails 4 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, twitter-bootstrap, libv8

I'm not exactly a seasoned veteran of the Rails world, but from what I've seen, I would definitely like to use bootstrap on my Rails projects.
i'm running windows 7 and I'm kind a married  to it.  I have read everything I can find on this topic and is it just not possible to install bootstrap-rails on windows?
Every time I try to install either  therubyracer or libv8 I get fatal errors that I can't resolve.
It won't install twitter-bootstrap-rails because I don't have those other two.

**Can someone either tell me how to install bootstrap on my windows box or point me to the information?**

I am so frustrated, i've been stuck with this for a few months now.

Answer (score 0):

Give [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) a try.  This should get around the need to compile the style sheets into less, since they are ported to sass with this project.  See Section A for gems to include in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8
```

> Because libv8 is the interface for the V8 engine used by therubyracer,
>   you may need to use libv8, even if you have V8 installed already. If
>   you wish to use your own V8 installation, rather than have it built
>   for you, use the --with-system-v8 option.
>   [Source](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8#bring-your-own-v8)

I'm would never suggest cheating on your operating system, I'm just saying you could dual-boot and she would *never know*.

[Bootstrap-Sass](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass%E2%80%8E) works for me too.